# RFID-RC522 not working, red led is on

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

I am working with RFID-RC522 and Arduino UNO. I have check pin configurations again and again tried different libraries. It is not reading card and red led on RC522 is consistently on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a picture of the card reader I have. If yours looks identical, then this library should work: https://github.com/ljos/MFRC522

[image]

The auth_read_write.ino sketch worked for me. Before you install the library, I recommend removing any other MFRC522 libraries from your arduino/library folder.

The only thing I did differently was used a 74HC4050 running at 3.3V between the Arduino and card reader. Some people claim you can connect the reader directly to the Arduino. I didn't want to take a chance of burning out the card reader so I used the 74HC4050.

Here's how I connected it:

```
Component markings and connections

|-------------------------------------------|
|   SPI    |  UNO  | 74HC4050  | RFID-RC522 |
|----------|-------|-----------|------------|
| SDA (SS) |  10   |     7     |            |
| SDA (SS) |       |     6     |    SDA     |
| SCK      |  13   |     5     |            |
| SCK      |       |     4     |    SCK     |
| MOSI     |  11   |     3     |            |
| MOSI     |       |     2     |    MOSI    |
| MISO     |  12   |           |    MISO    |
| IRQ      |  N/C  |    N/C    |    N/C     |
| GND      |  GND  | 8,9,11,14 |    GND     |
| RST      |   5   |           |    RST     |
| 3.3V     |       |     1     |    3.3V    |
|-------------------------------------------|
```